Binding Apache EChart in Grafana via HTTP API (Json)
We are reviewing Apache ECharts integration into Grafana.
We've managed to integrate most chart types, but we're stuck with the 'Treemap'.
We've seen examples like this: https://echarts.volkovlabs.io/d/FlnnZ4F4k/treemap?orgId=1&editPanel=6.
However, these rely mainly on static data, and we're planning to use a JSON-API(https://packages.xxx.com/nodes.json) data source.
Given that Treemap requires hierarchical data, we're struggling to integrate it using the JSON-API. We have a test API available at:

with script in grafana panel as below:


var thedata;

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://packages.xxx.com/nodes.json',
  type: "GET",
  success: function (data1) {
    thedata = JSON.stringify(data1);
    alert(thedata);
  }
});


return {
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    data: thedata
  }]
};



Could anyone provide guidance on how to bind a JSON-API data source to an Apache Treemap in Grafana, or offer a working sample? We've successfully connected the Treemap to static data but need help using dynamic data.
While use static data, it working, as below:


var thedata;

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://packages.xxx.com/nodes.json',
  type: "GET",
  success: function (data1) {
    thedata = JSON.stringify(data1);
    alert(thedata);
  }
});


return {
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    data: [
      {
        name: 'nodeA',
        value: 10,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'nodeAa',
            value: 4
          },
          {
            name: 'nodeAb',
            value: 6
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'nodeB',
        value: 20,
        children: [
          {
            name: 'nodeBa',
            value: 20,
            children: [
              {
                name: 'nodeBa1',
                value: 20
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
};






finally, we fixed it, by 2 changes as below：

let thedata = [];

$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'https://packages.xxx.com/nodes.json',
  type: "GET",
  async: false, // 将 async 设置为 false 以使请求同步   ---> (1)
  success: function (data1) {
    thedata = data1;   // (2)
    // alert(JSON.stringify(thedata));
  }
});

// setTimeout(() => {
//   console.log('2 seconds have passed');
// }, 5000);

return {
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    data: thedata
  }]
};



